# Ambiguous occurrence "map" error in WinHugs / Haskell

Tags: haskell

In WinHugs I've implemented the following function:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
map f [] = []
map f (x:l) = f x : map f l
```

This should simply run a function for each number in a list like:

```
Hugs> map (+ 1) [1,2,3]
```

should give

```
[2,3,4].
```

But when I try to load that *.hs script WinHugs gives the errormessage

```
ERROR file:.\script.hs:3 - Ambiguous variable occurrence "map"
*** Could refer to: Main.map Hugs.Prelude.map
```

line 3 is `map f (x:l) = f x : map f l`

How can I avoid that problem? I guess something in my preferences/settings is wrong.

Comment: Rename your function to, say, `map'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You’re seeing the error because the Haskell Prelude already defines a function named `map`. A simple–minded fix is to rename your definition, *e.g.*,

```
mymap :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
mymap f [] ...
```

The more sophisticated approach is to exclude the Prelude’s definition of `map` with

```
import Prelude hiding (map)
```

at the top of your module.

The accommodating approach is to leave the definition alone and apply the function you want by its full name, either

```
Main.map (+ 1) [1, 2, 3]
```

or

```
Prelude.map (+ 1) [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have two `map` functions in scope, the built-in `Prelude.map` and the one you've defined in `script.hs`.  You can either refer to it directly as

```
> Main.map (+1) [1, 2, 3]
```

Or you can just use the built-in `map`, since it's defined in the exact same way.

If you want to use `Prelude.map` with your custom `map` in scope, you can do

```
> Prelude.map (+1) [1, 2, 3]
```